# Split the string and join all first elements then second element and so on in c#

Tags: c#, .net, arrays, linq

I have a string like this -

```
var roleDetails = "09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9^Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000^Product Delivery - Download^1,24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A^Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000^Training Subscriber^1,6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6^Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000^License Manager - Home use^1,76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2^Account Admin^Account Admin^1,B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11^Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000^Co-Administrator^1,CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816^ReadOnly^ReadOnly^1,D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9^Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000^Product Delivery - DVD^1,E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4^Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER:0000^License Manager^1";
```

Spliting it with "," returns this -

```
[0] "09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9^Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000^Product Delivery - Download^1"
[1] "24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A^Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000^Training Subscriber^1"
[2] "6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6^Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000^License Manager - Home use^1"
[3] "76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2^Account Admin^Account Admin^1"    
[4] "B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11^Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000^Co-Administrator^1"  
[5] "CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816^ReadOnly^ReadOnly^1"
[6] "D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9^Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000^Product Delivery - DVD^1"
[7] "E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4^Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER:0000^License Manager^1"
```

All elements contains carat (^). so spliting each element further with ^ symbol will return four element.

But I want to join all first element then all second element and then third and so on and get the result like this -

```
[0]: 09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9, 24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A, 6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6, 76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2, B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11, CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816, D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9, E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4

[1]: Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000,Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000, Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000,Account Admin, Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000, ReadOnly, Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000, Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER

[2]: Product Delivery - Download, Training Subscriber, License Manager - Home use, Account Admin, Co-Administrator, ReadOnly, Product Delivery - DVD, License Manager
[3]: 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

What is the quickest and simplest way of achieving this?

## EDIT

This is what I tried so far -

```
var rolearray = roleDetails.Split(',').Select(s => s.Split('^')).Select(a => new { RoleId = a[0], RoleNme = a[1], FriendlyName = a[2], IsUserInRole = a[3] });
```

but again this is not returning the way I need it. But I want to join all a[0]s , then all a[1] and so on

SOLUTION: 
After comparing solutions and ran it 10 times in a loop to see the performance I found solution suggested by Jamiec is taking less time. So selecting this solution.

Comment: could you please at least post a first attempt of your own to solve this problem?

Comment: Your collection with 7 results splitted returns 4 elements? You want all first elements next to each other? (doesn't look like that in expected results). I honestly can't quite understand what you're asking

Comment: @MongZhu, I have edited it

Comment: In the `This is what I tried so far` you made an anonymous object... what does this have to do with it...?

Comment: @EpicKip: Assuming all elements are of the form `A^B^C^D`, the OP wants to combine all A elements, all B elements, etc. In essence, grouping the data by "columns" rather than "rows" (if that makes sense)

Comment: have you tried it the oldscool way, using 2 loops ?=!

Comment: Honestly if you're going to group in columns I'd say just make a class you fill :)

Comment: I can understand the desire for linq, it just looks so damn elegant always, but in a lot of cases unreadable and way too cryptic. I still would encourage you to solve it using loops and a temporary `List<string>` to save the results. You probably would have been done by now

Comment: @Flater yes exactly I want the same

Comment: @MongZhu: I disagree that linq makes this cryptic. OP trying to oneline the operation is making it cryptic. Nicely separated lines of code using Linq should not be unreadable (currently composing an answer to prove my point, give me a minute :))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The easiest way to do this, is to simply do:

```
var split = roleDetails.Split(',')
                .Select(x => x.Split('^').ToArray())
                .ToArray();
```

You would then access the elements like a <strike>multi dimensional</strike> jagged array

```
Console.WriteLine(split[0][0]);
// result: 09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/NEUVOR15080

And if you then want all the elements grouped

```
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",split.Select(x => x[0])));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",split.Select(x => x[1])));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",split.Select(x => x[2])));
Console.WriteLine(String.Join(",",split.Select(x => x[3])));
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/BZXLG67151

Comment: After comparing it with other solutions and ran it for 10 times and found that this is taking much less time.

Comment: @AnilPurswani If performance is critical for you, LINQ should be avoided. One-pass approach with StringBuilders would be the fastest.

Comment: `string.Split(char[])` already returns and array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b873y76a(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: And that's a jagged array not a multidimentional array.

Answer (score 16):

Pure LINQ solution:

```
roleDetails.Split(',')
    .SelectMany(x => x.Split('^').Select((str, idx) => new {str, idx}))
    .GroupBy(x => x.idx)
    .Select(grp => string.Join(", ", grp.Select(x => x.str)))
```

Comment: the only solution which does not use fixed/hard coded indices! +1 for the point that it will not break when the input should change some day.

Answer (score 5):

Here you can user Aggregate and Zip extension method of Linq.

**Aggregate:** Performs a specified operation to each element in a collection, while carrying the result forward.

**Zip:** The Zip extension method acts upon two collections. It processes each element in two series together.

```
var roleDetails = "09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9^Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000^Product Delivery - Download^1,24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A^Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000^Training Subscriber^1,6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6^Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000^License Manager - Home use^1,76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2^Account Admin^Account Admin^1,B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11^Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000^Co-Administrator^1,CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816^ReadOnly^ReadOnly^1,D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9^Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000^Product Delivery - DVD^1,E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4^Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER:0000^License Manager^1";
var rolearray = roleDetails.Split(',')
            .Select(s => s.Split('^'))
            .Aggregate((s1Array, s2Array) => s1Array.Zip(s2Array, (s1, s2) => s1 + "," + s2).ToArray());
```

Comment: Nice solution but the time taken by this approach is more then others. Thanks anyways for new type of solution

Answer (score 1):

```
string roleDetails = "09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9^Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000^Product Delivery - Download^1,24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A^Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000^Training Subscriber^1,6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6^Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000^License Manager - Home use^1,76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2^Account Admin^Account Admin^1,B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11^Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000^Co-Administrator^1,CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816^ReadOnly^ReadOnly^1,D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9^Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000^Product Delivery - DVD^1,E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4^Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER:0000^License Manager^1";
    var RawItems = roleDetails.Split(',').Select(x=> x.Split('^'));

    var Items1 = RawItems.Select(x=> x.ElementAt(0));       
    var Items2 = RawItems.Select(x=> x.ElementAt(1));
    var Items3 = RawItems.Select(x=> x.ElementAt(2));
    var Items4 = RawItems.Select(x=> x.ElementAt(3));
```

Comment: @Jamiec why is that?

Comment: `RawItems.Select` - enumerate the whole list once. `x.Take` enumerate `n` elements of that list. `x.Skip` enumerate `n` elements of the list again. So. many. implicit. loops.

Comment: You could have just done `x.ElementAt(2)` for example. Eliminating all the `skip/Take` madness.

Comment: @Jamiec: Extending your argument, String.Split returns an **array**, which can be much more easily accessed via index. `x.Skip(1).Take(1)` is equal to `x[1]`. Using a skip and take unnecessarily complicates the code. (edit: hadn't seen your second comment yet, the same argument applies for `x.ElementAt(1)`, though that is already much less contrived than the skip and take)

Comment: @Flater hence my answer :)

Comment: @Jamiec is it good now? thanks to you I learned something too.

Comment: Not in my opinion - its still bad, but at least you're not enumerating your collections to death.

Comment: @AnilPurswani Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

If you don't like the LINQ solutions, here's a solution without:

```
var result = new string[4];
var i = 0;
foreach(var line in roleDetails.Split(','))
    foreach(var piece in line.Split('^'))
        result[i++ % 4] += (i <= 4 ? "" : ",") + piece;
```

Basically, you split on commas and carets, and foreach on each, using a counter that tells us which array element to concatenate in, and whether to use a comma separator or not.

If your initial string is much bigger than in this example, consider first creating an array of StringBuilders first as these are better performing with concatenations:

```
var stringBuilders = new StringBuilder[4];
var result = new string[4];
var i = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    stringBuilders[i] = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var line in roleDetails.Split(','))
    foreach(var piece in line.Split('^'))
        stringBuilders[i++ % 4].Append((i <= 4 ? "" : ",") + piece);
foreach (var stringBuilder in stringBuilders)
    result[i++ % 4] = stringBuilder.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

One more LINQ solution. But not as clean as @Pavel's:

```
string a = "", b = "", c = "", d = "";
roleDetails.Split(',').ToList().ForEach(x =>
        {
            a += x.Split('^')[0] + ',';
            b += x.Split('^')[1] + ',';
            c += x.Split('^')[2] + ',';
            d += x.Split('^')[3] + ',';
        });
MessageBox.Show(a.Trim(','));
MessageBox.Show(b.Trim(','));
MessageBox.Show(c.Trim(','));
MessageBox.Show(d.Trim(','));
```

OUTPUT:

```
a = 09A880C2-8732-408C-BA09-4AD6F0A65CE9,24B11B23-1669-403F-A24D-74CE72DFD42A,6A4A6543-DB9F-46F2-B3C9-62D69D28A0B6,76B3B165-0BB4-4E3E-B61F-0C0292342CE2,B3C0CE51-00EE-4A0A-B208-98653E21AE11,CBA225BC-680C-4627-A4F6-BED401682816,D80CF5CF-CB6E-4424-9D8F-E29F96EBD4C9,E0275936-FBBB-4775-97D3-9A7D19D3E1B4
b = Z:WB:SELECT_DOWNLOAD:0000,Z:WB:TRAINING_SUBSCRIBER:0000,Z:WB:LIC_MGR_HOME_REDL:0000,Account Admin,Z:WB:1BENTLEY_ISA_ADMIN:0000,ReadOnly,Z:WB:MY_SELECT_CD:0000,Z:WB:LICENSE_MANAGER:0000
c = Product Delivery - Download,Training Subscriber,License Manager - Home use,Account Admin,Co-Administrator,ReadOnly,Product Delivery - DVD,License Manager
d = 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1
```

Comment: Why is this downvoted? It produces the result OP is looking for

Comment: This would work but it's a really bad technique.  This will loop and parse the strings way too many times.  And it will be very slow due to all of the string manipulation.

Comment: You are right there :) But OP didn't initially asked for better _performance_. Else I wouldn't even propose a LINQ  solution in the first place!

Comment: linq is plenty fast... this isn't linq.  `.ToList().ForEach(...)` alone causes the array result from the first `.Split(...)` to be looped twice.  and your `a,b,c,d` lines each reparse `x`.

Comment: Oh okay. point duly noted. Thanks for taking your time to explain :]

Answer (score 0):

Fairly clean and fast...

```
var sets = new[]
{
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string>(),
    new List<string>(),
};

foreach (var role in roleDetails.Split(','))
{
    var details = role.Split('^');
    sets[0].Add(details[0]);
    sets[1].Add(details[1]);
    sets[2].Add(details[2]);
    sets[3].Add(details[3]);
}

var lines = sets.Select(set => string.Join(",", set)).ToArray();
```

... little nuts to understand and doesn't really save anything on performance ...

```
var ret = roleDetails.Split(',')
        .Aggregate(seed: new { SBS = new[] { new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder(),
                                             new StringBuilder(), new StringBuilder(), },
                               Start = true },

        func: (seed, role) =>
        {
            var details = role.Split('^');

            if (seed.Start)
            {
                seed.SBS[0].Append(details[0]);
                seed.SBS[1].Append(details[1]);
                seed.SBS[2].Append(details[2]);
                seed.SBS[3].Append(details[3]);

                return new
                {
                    seed.SBS,
                    Start = false,
                };
            }
            else
            {
                seed.SBS[0].Append(',').Append(details[0]);
                seed.SBS[1].Append(',').Append(details[1]);
                seed.SBS[2].Append(',').Append(details[2]);
                seed.SBS[3].Append(',').Append(details[3]);

                return seed;
            }
        },
        resultSelector: result => result.SBS.Select(sb => sb.ToString()).ToArray()
        );
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `Tuple` here

```
var roles = roleDetails.Split(',')
            .Select(x => x.Split('^'))
            .Where(x=>x.Length==4)
            .Select(x=> 
             new Tuple<string, string, string, string>(x[0], x[1], x[2], x[3]))
            .ToList();

            var item1 = string.Join(",", roles.Select(x=>x.Item1).ToArray());     
            var item2 = string.Join(",", roles.Select(x => x.Item2).ToArray());
            var item3 = string.Join(",", roles.Select(x => x.Item3).ToArray());
            var item4 = string.Join(",", roles.Select(x => x.Item4).ToArray());
```

Answer (score -3):

Your attempt tries to do everything in a single line, which is making it much harder for you to understand what's happening.

You're already using all the tools you need (`Select()` and `Split()`). If you make your code more readable by separating everything into separate lines of code, then it becomes much easier to find your way:

```
//Your data string
string myDataString = "..."; 

//Your data string, separated into a list of rows (each row is a string)
var myDataRows = myDataString.Split(',');

//Your data string, separated into a list of rows (each row is a STRING ARRAY)
var myDataRowsAsStringArrays = myDataRows.Select(row => row.Split('^'))
```

And now, all you need to do is retrieve the correct data.

```
var firstColumnValues  = myDataRowsAsStringArrays.Select(row => row[0]);
var secondColumnValues = myDataRowsAsStringArrays.Select(row => row[1]);
var thirdColumnValues  = myDataRowsAsStringArrays.Select(row => row[2]);
var fourthColumnValues = myDataRowsAsStringArrays.Select(row => row[3]);
```

And if you so choose, you can join the values into a single comma separated string:

```
var firstColumnString  =  String.Join(", ", firstColumnValues);
var secondColumnString =  String.Join(", ", secondColumnValues);
var thirdColumnString  =  String.Join(", ", thirdColumnValues);
var fourthColumnString =  String.Join(", ", fourthColumnValues);
```

Comment: I'm open to improving my answer, if I could get some feedback as to what needs improving.